# How do I raise an error in an Execute Sql Task in Integration Services?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Let me also back up a step - I'm trying to implement a sanity check inside an IS package. The idea is that the entire package runs in a read uncommitted transaction, with the final step being a check that determines that certain row counts are present, that kind of stuff. If they are NOT, I want to raise an exception and rollback the transaction.

If you can tell me how to do this, or, even better, suggest a better way to implement a sanity check, that would be great.

Comment: Are you using staging tables or directly importing to production tables from the IS package? If using staging tables you could run sanity checks on those prior to inserting into production tables.

Comment: An entire staging database, in this case. The process for synching production with this staging db is separate. What I've got right now is an Execute Sql task, but all it can do is produce rowcounts, with no way to blow the package up if they're wrong.

Comment: If you know what the expected rowcount *should* be, then you could set a global variable for the package equal to that. Then edit the constraint condition to fail if the observed rowcount does not equal the expected variable.

Comment: Okay, I think we're zeroing in on it now...how do I compare the rowcount from the t-sql statement to the variable value?

Comment: Your result set from the Execute SQL Task that provides rowcount should be set to `Single Row`. Then in the constraint condition you would set it to `Expression and Constraint`. The Value would be `Failure`, and in your Expression you would set the `ResultSet <> GlobalVariable`. If they don't equal, the final step will fail the package.

Comment: Okay, I think this is the answer...go ahead and repost this and I'll accept it - thanks muchly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fail the package if your observed rowcount differs from your expected rowcount:

1. Create a Package Global Variable to hold your expected rowcount. This could be derived from a `RowCount` step in your DFT, set manually, etc.
2. Edit your `Execute SQL Task` that provides the observed rowcount, and set the Result Set to `Single Row`.
3. In the Result Set tab of your `Execute SQL Task`, assign this Result Set to a variable.
4. Edit your constraint condition prior to your final step. Set the Evaluation Operation to `Expression and Constraint`. Set the Value to `Failure`. In your expression, evaluate `ResultSetVariable <> ExpectedRowCountVariable`.

If the observed rowcount does not equal the expected rowcount, the package will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can raise an error and roll back the transaction in an SSIS "Execute SQL" task with the following SQL:

`Raiserror('Something went wrong',16,1)`

This will cause the "Execute SQL" task to return the error to the SSIS package and the task will follow the "red" (failure) path. You can then use this path to rollback the transaction and do any tidying-up.

This approach has the advantage you can do all your processing in the Execute SQL task then call Raiserror if you need to.